# Spark SQL `elt` function converts to String?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was looking through the Spark functions, and `elt` caught my eye. `elt returns the n-th input`.

However, for some reason, `elt` converts my stuff to strings:

`SELECT elt(1, *) FROM VALUES TIMESTAMP '2021-08-17T13:20:00.000Z'`

```
+----------------------------+
|elt(1, CAST(col1 AS STRING))|
+----------------------------+
|         2021-08-17 13:20:00|
+----------------------------+
```

Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong? Converting to string seems like a very arbitrary limitation for such a basic function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview2/sql-migration-guide.html#upgrading-from-spark-sql-24-to-30) is the only information I could find regarding this issue:

> Since Spark 2.3, when all inputs are binary, SQL elt() returns an
> output as binary. Otherwise, it returns as a string. Until Spark 2.3,
> it always returns as a string despite of input types. To keep the old
> behavior, set spark.sql.function.eltOutputAsString to true.